# NzPaginationComponent got TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

After I update ng-zorro-antd to Version 1.1.1, and Angular to version 6.0.7, I got the following error for NzPaginationComponent.html:1 :

ERROR TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function
    at ViewContainerRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewContainerRef_.createEmbeddedView (core.js:8559)
    at NgTemplateOutlet.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgTemplateOutlet.ngOnChanges (common.js:3834)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9038)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10306)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10268)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:10901)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:10861)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (NzPaginationComponent.html:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:10853)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10250).

Anything I missed to update or I need to amend my code?

Answer (score 3):

may be you should have a look option [nzShowTotal], it should be specified a template.

`[nzShowTotal]="totalTpl"
......
 <ng-template #totalTpl let-range="range" let-total>{{ 'Total: ' + total}}</ng-template>`

Comment: Thank you, this issue has been settled.

Comment: Thanks. Good solution